# Are there enum columns in flutter-moor ORM?

Tags: flutter-moor

I have not found any documentation about possibility built in Enum columns in Flutter ORM moor. What is the best way to create enum column? I want this:

```
enum PersistentType {
  File,
  Database
}

class Recipes extends Table {
  IntColumn get id => integer().autoIncrement()();
  TextColumn get title => text().withLength(max: 16)();
  TextColumn get instructions => text()();
  EnumColumn get persType=> enum<PersistentType>().nullable()(); // TODO Not possible??
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Type Converter for enum or custom object.

doc: 
https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/advanced-features/type_converters/

example:
https://github.com/simolus3/moor/issues/521

Answer (score 5):

Moor now supports enums as integers representing the index of the enums. Read [the documentation](https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/advanced-features/type_converters/#implicit-enum-converters) for more info.

```dart
IntColumn get persType=> intEnum<PersistentType>().nullable()();
```